# Where does the hadoop CopytoLocal commands , gets logged?

Tags: hadoop, logging, copy

I would like to know when a file is copied from hadoop to local , where this information gets  logged . I have looked into the hadoop audit logs and namenode logs , i did not see this information getting logged . Any help would be greatly appreciated .

Comment: I don't understand the question. What exactly do you want to see logged?

Comment: I would like to see the copy command in the logs , or some entry that would say that someone is trying to copy a file from hadoop to local .

Comment: I don't think this kind of information is logged, and I don't see a point as to why it should.

Comment: This would help to find any sensitive data exfiltration .

Answer (score 0):

`CopyToLocal` can copy files to the local file system. This process refers to many class and method, so you'd better see the hadoop-hadoop-namenode-Master.log, hadoop-hadoop-jobtracker-Master.log, hadoop-hadoop-datanode-Slave1.log in your logs. I would give some myself understanding about write files. The process of read is similar to the process of write file.

You can search "cmd=mkdirs" in hadoop-hadoop-namenode-Master.log,and you can search "HDFS_WRITE" and so on. These key words presents the process of write files,that is `put` or `CopyFromLocal`. Then,you can read these logs  according to your purpose .

Note:You'd better find your logs in master node and slave node respectively, the above logs' name is just in my computer.